# Freezed class with generic type and fromJson, toJson

Tags: dart, generics, freezed, flutter-freezed

I'm trying to make a [Freezed class with a generic type that has](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#deserializing-generic-classes) `toJson` and `fromJson`:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'option.freezed.dart';
part 'option.g.dart';

@Freezed(genericArgumentFactories: true)
class Option<TData> with _$Option<TData> {
  const factory Option(
      {required TData id,
      required String name,
      String? fontFamily,
      required int iconCodePoint}) = _Option;

  const factory Option.empty({
    @Default(0) int iconCodePoint,
    @Default(0 as TData) TData id,
    @Default('') String name,
    @Default(null) String? fontFamily,
  }) = _Empty;

  factory Option.fromJson(
          Map<String, dynamic> json, TData Function(Object?) fromJsonTData) =>
      _$OptionFromJson(json, fromJsonTData);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(Object? Function(TData) toJsonTData) {
    return _$$_OptionToJson<TData>(this as _$_Option<TData>, toJsonTData);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _$$_OptionToJson<TData>(
    _$_Option<TData> instance,
    Object? Function(TData value) toJsonTData,
  ) =>
      <String, dynamic>{
        'id': toJsonTData(instance.id),
        'name': instance.name,
        'fontFamily': instance.fontFamily,
        'iconCodePoint': instance.iconCodePoint,
        'runtimeType': instance.$type,
      };
}
```

The build runner executes the code generation without error, but when I try to run the app I get:

> ```
> Error: The non-abstract class '_$_Option' is missing implementations
> for these members: lib/…/option/option.freezed.dart:190
>      - Option._$$_OptionToJson
>     Try to either
>      - provide an implementation,
>      - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
>      - mark the class as abstract, or
>      - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
>     class _$_Option<TData> implements _Option<TData> {
>           ^^^^^^^^^ : Context: 'Option._$$_OptionToJson' is defined here. lib/…/option/option.dart:30
>       Map<String, dynamic> _$$_OptionToJson<TData>(
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ : Error: The non-abstract class '_$_Empty' is missing implementations for these members:
> lib/…/option/option.freezed.dart:403
>      - Option._$$_OptionToJson
>     Try to either
>      - provide an implementation,
>      - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
>      - mark the class as abstract, or
>      - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
>     class _$_Empty<TData> implements _Empty<TData> {
>           ^^^^^^^^ : Context: 'Option._$$_OptionToJson' is defined here. lib/…/option/option.dart:30
>       Map<String, dynamic> _$$_OptionToJson<TData>(
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ : Error: Type variables can't be used in static members. lib/…/option/option.freezed.dart:406
>           this.id = 0 as TData,
>                          ^^^^^ : Error: Type variables can't be used as constants. lib/…/option/option.freezed.dart:406
>           this.id = 0 as TData,
>                          ^^^^^ : Error: Type variables can't be used as constants. lib/…/option/option.dart:16
>         @Default(0 as TData) TData id,
> ```

It looks like in the docs we don't need `toJson` but when I remove it I get this error in all the classes that contain a field of type `Option`

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: -1

when I run the build runner. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the first constructor be

```
const factory Option.option(
```

?

I had a similar problem, see https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/766

Comment: Haha oops just saw this after viewing an update on the github issue. I have a `const factory ClassName(` default constructor in all my freezed classes so off the top of my head this should be fine.